# Kafka Connect Bigquery Sink Connector - Offset commit failed during close

Tags: apache-kafka, google-bigquery, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to set up [Kafka Connect BigQuery sink connector](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-bigquery).
I have around >50 kafka topics. When I deploy the connector, initially 10(which is I think threadPoolSize default value in connector config) tables show up with some data. Then, new data stops coming to tables. Also, no new table show up in BigQuery.

My connector config:

```
{
   "name": "kcbq-connect1",
   "config": {
     "connector.class": "com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.BigQuerySinkConnector",
     "tasks.max" : "1",
     "topics" : "topic1,topic2,topic2",
     "sanitizeTopics" : "true",
     "autoCreateTables" : "true",
     "autoUpdateSchemas" : "true",     
     "schemaRetriever" : "com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.schemaregistry.schemaretriever.SchemaRegistrySchemaRetriever",
     "schemaRegistryLocation":"http://localhost:8081",
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
    "bufferSize": "100000",
    "maxWriteSize":"10000",
    "tableWriteWait": "1000",
     "project" : "my-project-89507",
     "datasets" : ".*=my_cdc",
     "keyfile" : "/home/debezium/key.json"
     
   }
 }
```

This is what I get when I query connector status:

```
{
  "name": "kcbq-connect1",
  "connector": {
    "state": "RUNNING",
    "worker_id": "10.1.0.37:8083"
  },
  "tasks": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "state": "FAILED",
      "worker_id": "10.1.0.37:8083",
      "trace": "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:588)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:323)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:226)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:198)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:185)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:235)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\nCaused by: com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.exception.BigQueryConnectException: Some write threads encountered unrecoverable errors: com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.exception.BigQueryConnectException; See logs for more detail\n\tat com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.batch.KCBQThreadPoolExecutor.maybeThrowEncounteredErrors(KCBQThreadPoolExecutor.java:112)\n\tat com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.BigQuerySinkTask.put(BigQuerySinkTask.java:190)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:560)\n\t... 10 more\n"
    }
  ],
  "type": "sink"
}
```

trace logs:

```
[2020-12-05 13:07:22,399] WARN WorkerSinkTask{id=kcbq-connect1-0} Offset commit failed during close (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:389)
[2020-12-05 13:07:22,399] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=kcbq-connect1-0} Commit of offsets threw an unexpected exception for sequence number 2: null (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:261)
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.batch.CountDownRunnable@6231b75c rejected from com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.batch.KCBQThreadPoolExecutor@4ebc3f40[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 65]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2063)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:830)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1379)
        at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.write.batch.KCBQThreadPoolExecutor.awaitCurrentTasks(KCBQThreadPoolExecutor.java:92)
        at com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.BigQuerySinkTask.flush(BigQuerySinkTask.java:129)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.sink.SinkTask.preCommit(SinkTask.java:125)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.commitOffsets(WorkerSinkTask.java:386)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.closePartitions(WorkerSinkTask.java:618)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.access$1300(WorkerSinkTask.java:71)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask$HandleRebalance.onPartitionsRevoked(WorkerSinkTask.java:694)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.invokePartitionsRevoked(ConsumerCoordinator.java:312)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onLeavePrepare(ConsumerCoordinator.java:751)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.close(AbstractCoordinator.java:976)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.close(ConsumerCoordinator.java:895)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.close(KafkaConsumer.java:2373)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.close(KafkaConsumer.java:2340)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.close(KafkaConsumer.java:2290)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.closeQuietly(Utils.java:964)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.close(WorkerSinkTask.java:171)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doClose(WorkerTask.java:164)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:191)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:235)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2020-12-05 13:07:22,400] INFO [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-kcbq-connect1-0, groupId=connect-kcbq-connect1] Member connector-consumer-kcbq-connect1-0-f7533028-4e1a-4492-9f56-9b2d7bc1bc4e sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator <hostname>:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) due to the consumer is being closed (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:1005)
```

Can Kafka experts here guide me in the right direction to fix the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was fixed when I switched from Bigquery Sink Connector version 1.6.6 to 1.6.1.